# Local Java Cache library supporting multiple map tiers?

Tags: java, caching

I am looking for a Java based caching library that supports multiple standard Map interfaces as tiers (that I for instance could use for on-heap, off-heap and flash based maps) i.e. instead of layering multiple independent caches that each keep their own eviction mechanism I want a SINGLE logic that will move entries between the tiers as they becomes more or less frequently used.
My use-case involves a huge number of relatively small entries so holding separate caches where each lower level also holds the entries of the previous tiers as well as resulting in duplication of usage meta data for each key would be very storage inefficient.
The access time must be as low and consistent as possible so not considering distributed/remote cache tiers (Redis, Memcached...) in this case.

Comment: You probably want to look at distributed caching frameworks. For example Infinispan's [passivation](https://infinispan.org/docs/13.0.x/titles/configuring/configuring.html#persistence) appears to behave how you want. You could then enable their on-heap and off-heap caches. Each tier does its own eviction logic, which I think is fair as they have different working sets, latencies, and operate concurrently. See others like Hazelcast, Ignite, Coherence, etc. (Ehcache appears to use [inclusive tiers](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.9/tiering.html#multi-tier-sequence-flow)).

Comment: As mentioned in the question I am NOT looking for a distributed cache.

Comment: Correct, which means you simply do not turn on those features.

Comment: Great - now looking into Infinispan that potentially look promising...